# how to change the color of the tabs indicator text in android?

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

how to change the color of the text indicator of tab? i can change the icon using selector tag refered the [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). but cant to the text color. how?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Style it 
  in your custom theme  change

```
<item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@android:style/Widget.TabWidget</item>
```

and

```
<style name="Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>  


<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/tab_indicator_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @DroidBase, @Alex Volovoy, where should i place the styles. When I put it as a separate xml file under values folder, got the error `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget'.`

Comment: @Mithun: Please post some code snippet find the exact solution. My guess is you did not mention the parent attribute. that is override the default style of an xml object

Comment: hey @Alex, looking nice but i m not able to give it a try.... its my first time with styles... could you please elaborate what you are trying to say? @DroidBase you also please explain what you are trying to say in apidemos comment??????

Comment: @Farhan depending on which parent theme you're using, you could add something like 
<style name="Widget.TabWidget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"></style>. 
This will make the attribute found.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but only worked for me with Robert's comment here to set parent.  To set the necessary attribute **parent** without having to figure out another theme you want to use, you can use this `parent="@style/AppTheme"` to use the existing AppTheme style in styles.xml

Answer (score 29):

Here is a new answer I found from Fred Grott (http://knol.google.com/k/fred-grott/advance-tabs/) after a little web searching.

This lets you set a `selector` for text color so a different color can be used when tab is selected or not.  Which can be very useful if you are using a different background color for the tab if its selected.  Of course you can also just throw in a plain color and not a selector.

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) tabWidget.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);        
tv.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.text_tab_indicator));
```

Where R.color.text_tab_indicator is a [selector xml file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) located in your res/drawable folder.

In other words, the indicator text really is a `TextView` which is retrievable via the `View` object which can be accessed from the `TabWidget` object.

Take a look at Fred's examples for more info and context regarding the variable declarations as well as other tricks.

Comment: tv is null, findViewById(android.R.id.title) does not find it

Answer (score 20):

Danny C's answer is 100% correct.I just  wanted to add something to it to make a complete answer  with resource file.

The text_tab_indicator under res/color file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:textColor="@color/text_tab_selected"
    android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:textColor="@color/text_tab_unselected"
    android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

And this text_tab_unselected & text_tab_selected will look like this under colors/values folder

```
<resources> 
<color name="text_tab_selected">#ffffff</color>
<color name="text_tab_unselected">#95ab45</color>
```

After that finally add  Dannyy's answer in tab class file

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) tabWidget.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);        
tv.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.text_tab_indicator));
```

Comment: `android:textColor` should be `android:color` in text_tab_indicator.xml file.

Comment: getColorStateList is deprecated, so use ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.text_tab_indicator).

Comment: fails because tv is null, doesn't seem to be able to find a TextView with id title. My code is in the OnCreate of the fragment containing the TabLayout

Answer (score 6):

The change in color can also be stated without using java - which is probably better.

I made changes to the text_tab_indicator (notice textColor was changed to 'color'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/text_tab_selected" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/text_tab_unselected" />
</selector>
```

Set the style of the TabWidget to point to a specific style in your xml code:

```
<TabWidget
    ...
    style="@style/TabText"
    />
```

Declare your text_tab_indicator located in /res/color as you desired color in the style

```
<style name="TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text_color</item>
</style>
```

It worked like a charm (for me).

Cheers,
Randall

Comment: Though this solution looks perfect, it hasn't worked on both of my devices (Android 5 and 2.3).