# Text on Tab of TabView

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-widget

I want to put the text on the every tab  of my application and also want to change its color from default. . . How it is Possible ?

Comment: Would please you stop tagging your questions android-ndk, it is very annoying. They have *nothing* to do with the NDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have defined a custom style for tab in my one of the application.

Which is something like:

(Note: define this style inside the styles.xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/LightTabWidget</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LightTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
        <!-- set textColor to red, so you can verify that it applied. -->
        <!-- <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>  -->
        <item name="android:textSize">12px</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#1E90FF</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and give this theme in the application tag inside AndroidManifest.xml file as:

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

### Update:

Still you are already done with solutions for the problem, let me suggest an example which is also valid: [how to change the color of the tabs indicator text in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804688/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-tabs-indicator-text-in-android/2957806#2957806)

Comment: where i hv put the styles.xml file. . . ??

Comment: @Shreyash its inside the Values folder.

Comment: @Shreyash check my updated answer, and put this code inside styles.xml inside the values folder.

Comment: Now the file has no error but there is no any effect on My current Tab text. . . What should be problem ?

Comment: @Shreyash glad to have your response quickly. But after having problem, what you have done to have solution?

Comment: Sorry, I was just checking the View. . . as i lost the Default view.. I got the Tabview Background as Black in normal and while it is selected it will shown gray colour. . .  Before it will shown White while selected and gray in normal view. . .

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
private View createTabIndicator(String text) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab);
    button.setText(text);
    button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    return button;
}
...
getTabHost().addTab(getTabHost().newTabSpec("name").setIndicator(createTabIndicator("name")).setContent(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of doing this,

```
TabSpec pecHome = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home").setIndicator("Home",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home)).setContent(intentHome);
tabHost.addTab(specHome);
```

here ssetIndicator will enable you to display the text.

Thats all 
Best Reagrds
Anup

Comment: Thanks, but i want to change the colout of it. . . I want to change the colour of the Indicator. .

Comment: I think this will help you tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); //unselected

Comment: Will u please give me Some More detail code. .  as i didnt get u proper. . .

Comment: is "getTabWidget()" a ready made method ? or Custom Function ?