# How do I set the color for a tabview in android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-tabhost

I want to change the colour of a tabview from the [default](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/images/hello-tabwidget.png) grey (and black when not selected) to red and green when not selected.

In the tab Widget class I'm trying to set the colour using these functions

```
tabHost.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
tabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

But they don't work, its still the [default](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/images/hello-tabwidget.png) colour. How do I manually set the background and tab colours of a tab widget in android? Also, is it possible to do it in xml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text on Tab of TabView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742107/text-on-tab-of-tabview)

Comment: @Lukas Knuth Your proposed duplicate question is for changing the colour of the text in the tab. My question is for changing the text colour. This is for changing the colour of the ACTUAL TAB itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Step 4. at this blog, it's how I have done it, very simple, easy to change and tweak if you need to and it's all in XML.

[Custom tabs in android tabhost](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)