# Android TabSpec text padding

Tags: android, tabs, padding

I need to add some padding on tabWidget element.
Im trying to add padding on text below image.

I'm trying with this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabHost.getChildAt(i).setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

    }
```

But it seems like nothing happens.

Here's xml:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Are you using a custom layout file for your tab widget?

Comment: There, I've added xml code.

Comment: Do you have something like "tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabitem, this.tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);" in your code?

Comment: Nope, just SetIndicator with String and Int. Do I have to make my own tabSpec layout and inflate it?

Comment: No, you don't need to. I just wanted to know if we were working with the default layout or a custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from a similar question, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804688/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-tabs-indicator-text-in-android).

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) tabWidget.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);        
tv.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
```