# Font color in tab indicator

Tags: android, tabs

I am using tabs in my app programatically i.e using tabspec. im not able to change the color of font of indicator the tab.
I am able to change the background color of the tab.

Comment: refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804688/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-tabs-indicator-text-in-android

Comment: What is EXACTLY your question ?

Comment: im usiong two tabs. In that i have text of that particular tab i want to change the font style of that text and styles of tabs too @OcuS

Answer (score 0):

Create custom theme to change colors of tabs or tab indicator go to this link

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100

Comment: im using tabs in android 2.2 api 8 i think action bar is not supported  in that version

Comment: If u want to use actionbar u can by using sheralock action bar https://github.com/t2health/ActionBarSherlock-Android