# Tabs of TabLayout not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a main activity, which hosts a fragment, which in turn hosts a TabLayout (with a ViewPager). The tab bar is shown, baut the tabs themselves are not shown.

Here is my code in the main activity for displaying the host fragment:

```
        Fragment fragment = new BMITabsFragment();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(Constants.BMI_TABS_FRAGMENT).commit();
```

Here is my the Fragment which hosts the TabLayout, which is BMITabsFragment (s.a.):

```
public class BMITabsFragment extends Fragment {
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new BMIFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
            getActivity()));

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bmitabs, container, false);
    return view;
}
...
}
```

This is my FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class BMIFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private Context context;

public BMIFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentManager = fm;

}

public BMIFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    fragmentManager = fm;

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    String[] pageTitles = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.page_titles_array);
    return pageTitles[position];
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_FILE, 0);
    long patientId = prefs.getLong(Constants.SELECTED_PATIENT_ID, 1);
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return BMITabelleFragment.newInstance(patientId);

        case 1:
            return BMIChartFragment.newInstance(patientId);

        default:
            return BMITabelleFragment.newInstance(patientId);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}
}
```

And this is the fragment_bmitabs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My code is based on the Google Android Guide at https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

What I am missing here?

Note: I am using AppCompatActivity and the support libraries v4 & v7 and the com:android:support:design library

Comment: a simple update in styles.xml - along the lines of `<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" parent="@style/AppTheme">` ..  worked for me - answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2805256/2162226

Answer (score 51):

This fixed it for me:

```
tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
});
```

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180462

Comment: Absurd... documentation says "This view also supports being used as part of a ViewPager's decor, and can be added directly to the ViewPager in a layout resource file like so" suggesting that if you use this view in this way you don't need to call that method.

Comment: not working on me. fragments of tab still not showing

Answer (score 9):

Set tab icons after `setupWithViewPager()`

```
private void setTabs {
   tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
   setupTabIcons();
} 

private void setupTabIcons() {
   tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
   tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
   tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to fix the link in this answer. Right now it points to 'enter link description here'.

Comment: That worked for me, the viewPager allready initialize the Tabs, just grabbing the tab with getTabAt() and set Text, Icon or CustomView worked!

Answer (score 6):

like @Nathaniel Ford said，this should a bug, I change to use design library 23.0.1。google fixed it,so change `build.gradle` to `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`. ps:you also must change your `compileSdkVersion`to 23

Comment: Thank you... this worked for me. The poor quality of Google's API keeps surprising me, it's just astonishing.

Answer (score 2):

**None of the other answers worked for me, I tried all of them**

However, this one did: [TabLayout not showing tabs after adding navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367217/tablayout-not-showing-tabs-after-adding-navigation-bar)

According to that answer, you have to enclose your `TabLayout` in a `AppBarLayout`. Why? Who knows. But at least it works.

Example Code (taken from that post):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout2"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"

        ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout2">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `android:tabPadding` attribute in Tablayout of xml file,remove it.

Comment: As this could be a valid answer, please elaborate it a bit more and explain why. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** instead of **FragmentPagerAdapter**.
It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If someone, in future, works with TabLayout along with ViewPager2 and faces same issue. Just add `.attach();` at end of `new TabLayoutMediator()`.

```
new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayoutRef, viewPager2Ref, (tab, position) -> tab.setText("Tab No. "+position)).attach();
```