# Android TabLayout not visible on my application

Tags: android

I'm trying to add simple TabLayout on my application, but it doesn't visible, view pager work fine

this layout is `toolbar_layout`

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and my main layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/content_background">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/application_toolbar"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-25dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

        <com.lapism.searchview.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

as i said view pager work fine, but tabs not visible on my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabLayout` should not be in `Toolbar`.

Check [this repository](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) as sample of using `CoordinatorLayout`, `DrawerLayout`, `Toolbar`, `TabLayout`.

Here is [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/043d883a0f38a1a481caeb1db318a36d5c5ff8dd/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) and [include_list_view.xml](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/043d883a0f38a1a481caeb1db318a36d5c5ff8dd/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml).

The view hierarchy is like this:

```
DrawerLayout
 - CoordinatorLayout
   - AppBarLayout
     - Toolbar
     - TabLayout
   - ViewPager
 - NavigationView
```

Answer (score 1):

Main Layout

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/content_background">

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/application_toolbar"/>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
<!-- Change this -->
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
<!-- Code -->
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-25dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigationView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
                app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

            <com.lapism.searchview.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `android:layout_height` of the `LinearLayout` is set to match parent that hides the `TabLayout`. Change `android:layout_height` to `0dp` and set `android:layout_weight` to `1`. I think this may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you put your `TabLayout` inside the `Toolbar`.
Try to change your `toolbar_layout` to this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>    
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        <!-- Tabs-->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The FrameLayout is the main content view of the activity.

Answer (score -2):

I actually found someone else's answer here.

[Tabs of TabLayout not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544617/tabs-of-tablayout-not-showing)

```
tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't copy an answer from another StackOverflow question. Rather, mark this question as a duplicate. Or put the StackOverflow link as a comment under the question if it's not exactly a duplicate.