# TabLayout not showing tabs after adding navigation bar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

i am working with ViewPager + TabLayout. It was working fine, but after i added navigation bar, the TabLayout is not showing tabs. I searched for solution but none of them helped. It will be really helpful if anyone tells me why this happened.

MainActivity.java

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    SimpleFragmentPageAdapter adapter = new SimpleFragmentPageAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

content_main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    style="@style/CategoryTab"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabTextColor="#ddd"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: show your full code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer this code. Add the tab layout inside a appbar layout.Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout2"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"

        ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout2">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Please try this, if error is not cleared means comment it.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) Can you tell me why this happened?

Comment: Guess we'll never know.